# Sum of Rows in DataTable by LinkedId in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, dataset

I have a DataTable that has transactions that a user can take. How can I display the sum of the EstimatedTransTime by LinkedId, and after it is summed show the largest transaction for that LinkedTickedId?

[image]

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables[0];

DataTable newDataTable
    = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => !ListLinkedIds.Contains(r.Field<int>("LinkedTicketId")))
        .CopyToDataTable();

gvMain.DataSource = newDataTable;
gvMain.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be like this

SELECT TicketID, DisplayNum, TranstypeDesc,
   SubQueueId, SUM(EstimatedTransTime),LinkedTicketId FROM vwQueueData WHERE
   (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Issued), 0) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,
   GETDATE()), 0)) AND QId = @QId AND SubId = @SubId AND Called IS NULL
  group by LinkedTicketId

try this and let me know if any wrong there

Comment: It doesnt work since you have to group all fields in other to display them and if you group all of them then it wont give a correct result.

Comment: I have little bit confusion in you question. i.e. in yopur table  LinkedTicketId = 10 have different value in TranstypeDesc column. Then how can select which value should be show in next gridview of that particular case!

Comment: The one with highest EstimatedTransTime will be displayed